# Extract value of substrings and sum results

Tags: xml, grep

I'm trying to extract all the values of a substring from this xml, then sum their totals. I can get the number of times the substring is mentioned, or a print out of the substring label, but never the values. I'm very much a beginner so I'm still learning. I'm looking into awk, but still figuring that one out too. Here's a few things I've tried.

```
grep -o "dur=[^;]*"
```

That gives me the times dur is mentioned

```
grep -o dur=
```

and that just prints out "dur=" the amount of times it's in the xml.

Here's the text of the xml file I'm testing with. Any pointers would be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MediaProfile xmlns="http://xmlns.sony.net/pro/metadata/mediaprofile" createdAt="2020-01-15T12:21:23Z" version="2.30">
    <Properties>
        <System systemId="0817072B1C" systemKind="AXS-R7 ver.4.010"/>
        <Attached mediaId="BD628805C22B1C080046021707" mediaKind="AXSMemoryCard"
            mediaName="T001CZZA"/>
    </Properties>
    <Contents>
        <Material uri="./Clip/T001C001_200114Q7/T001C001_200114Q7.mxf"
            type="MXF" offset="0" dur="1708" fps="24p" pixelAspect="2:1" flip="none" ch="4"
            videoType="F55_X-OCN_XT_6K_3:2" audioType="LPCM24"
            umid="2B340101010501010D4313000000F35C4CC7628805DC0800460217072B1C"
            status="none">
            <RelevantInfo uri="./Clip/T001C001_200114Q7/T001C001_200114Q7M01.xml" type="XML"/>
        </Material>
        <Material uri="./Clip/T001C002_2001153S/T001C002_2001153S.mxf"
            type="MXF" offset="0" dur="1668" fps="24p" pixelAspect="2:1" flip="none" ch="4"
            videoType="F55_X-OCN_XT_6K_3:2" audioType="LPCM24"
            umid="2B340101010501010D4313000000E7AF386D638805DC0800460217072B1C"
            status="none">
            <RelevantInfo uri="./Clip/T001C002_2001153S/T001C002_2001153SM01.xml" type="XML"/>
        </Material>
        <Material uri="./Clip/T001C003_200115RI/T001C003_200115RI.mxf"
            type="MXF" offset="0" dur="1752" fps="24p" pixelAspect="2:1" flip="none" ch="4"
            videoType="F55_X-OCN_XT_6K_3:2" audioType="LPCM24"
            umid="2B340101010501010D431300000024924F6E638805C50800460217072B1C"
            status="none">
            <RelevantInfo uri="./Clip/T001C003_200115RI/T001C003_200115RIM01.xml" type="XML"/>
        </Material>
        <Material uri="./Clip/T001C004_200115RH/T001C004_200115RH.mxf"
            type="MXF" offset="0" dur="1464" fps="24p" pixelAspect="2:1" flip="none" ch="4"
            videoType="F55_X-OCN_XT_6K_3:2" audioType="LPCM24"
            umid="2B340101010501010D4313000000A1C1536F638805DF0800460217072B1C"
            status="none">
            <RelevantInfo uri="./Clip/T001C004_200115RH/T001C004_200115RHM01.xml" type="XML"/>
        </Material>
    </Contents>
</MediaProfile>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser:

```
xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//@dur' file | awk '{sum+=$0} END{print sum}'
```

Output:

```
6592
```

Comment: `print sum+0` so you get numeric output even if no `dur=` exists in the input.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I'm going to read up on xmlstarlet to learn more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, as in your sample input, `dur=...` can only appear once per line and doesn't appear in any other context then with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/dur="([^"]+)"/,a){sum+=a[1]} END{print sum+0}' file
6592
```

otherwise using any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/dur="[^"]+"/){sum+=substr($0,RSTART+5)} END{print sum+0}' file
6592
```